# How to link JTexfeilds and their positions to JSlider?

Tags: java, swing, position, jslider

Is it possible?
For example I have JTextfeilds which i use to label an image via a mouse pressed listener(makes new label every time the mouse is clicked).

I then move on to the next image and add more label(the images are attached to the JSlider).

So what im asking is whether or not it is possible to attach the labels i create for each image to the jslider? or possibly the image?

At the moment when i create new labels on the next image it keeps them when i return to the previous image.

Any help would be appreciated.

The images are depends on the JSlider by the user uploading a folder of images, the image names then get put into a list. Using a loop i then change which image is shown depending on the slider value.

[1 partially labelled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptC1O.png)

So this is the first images labelled with JTextfeilds.

[New labels added on new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXdDY.png)

This is a new image with some added labels, what i want to be able to do is return to the previous image without the new labels, while being able to go back to this image with the new labels.

Comment: What is for you "link" and "attach"? Please explain what you want. What should be performed with JTextField when JSlider changes its value?

It would also be nice when you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which describes your problem.

Comment: The JTextfield and its position should be saved to the value of the JSlider, so when i return to that JSlider value its how i left it without any new JTextfields that may of been added on a different JSlider Value. Adding image which may make it more clear.

Comment: @Keags can you edit question with more details .plz clarify .still unclear to me

Comment: @Keags ok so if i understand ur question ,you have list of images and want to show different images relative to jslider position.
if so , you can create a array of image icons and set image to one lable .or you can use card layout and bring relative lable to front

Comment: Ive got the images changing relative to the JSlider, i want the JLabels which i put on the images to change relative to the JSlider or Image. E.g. labels: 1,2,3,4 on image 0.    1.1,1.2,2,3.1,3.2,4 on image 1 but when i go back to 0 the changes stay.

Comment: the jlabels?? where are they? did you show any code?? Just stop kidding around

Comment: The numbers on the images i posted.